# How to load a separate UIView in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, uiview, xib, xcode-storyboard

I have to use an UIView as a kind of Pause view when clicking on the pause button in the game that I develop now.
This pause view will be used in 40 UIViewControllers. I use "storyboard" for my UI but I have designed the pause view in a .xib file.

How to load and to use this view in my application? How just to load an UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this view to your view controller and set it to disabled using [yourView setEnabled:NO]; and then enable it when you need to using setEnabled:YES.

Or if you have multiple view controllers that's gonna use it. Create a separate view controller and put your view in it. Add this view controller's view programmatically to each view controller.

```
PauseViewController *pauseVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PauseID"];
[self.view addSubview:pauseVC.view];
```

[image: class]
[image: id]

Comment: In the .xib file, the view is just an UIView but not a view controller!

Comment: Putting it in a UIViewController is a possible solution.

Comment: Basel > I use your code but anything happens!??? The added view controller does not diplay.

Comment: Please give me more details on what you did. Adding the view controller using my code alone is not enough. Did you put your pause view in a new view controller? Is that view controller of class PauseViewController? I will edit my code to include a screenshot. Also, since you're using storyboard, you will need  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.

Comment: I found in the related topics a starting of solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428371/how-to-create-a-custom-uiview) `code`NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:nil options:nil];
UIView *fv = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] retain];

// now you have the view, do something with it:
fv.center = CGPointMake(100,100);
[self.view addSubview:fv];

Comment: The approach I gave you is tested and works as expected. If the solution in that topic solved your problem, I'm glad to hear that :)